# Java oracle search

Tags: java, oracle, search, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown menu that has list of column names from certain table in the database and I have textbox where user can type what one is looking for. User first selects the column from dropdown menu and types on textbox what s/he is looking for. I am kind of lost how can i match those dropdown column name and textbox string to look under specific column in oracle database.. Any sample code or suggestion would be helpful.. Thank you

Comment: Is this a Swing application or a web application?

Answer (score 2):

```
   String colname = request.getParameter("colname");//get the column name from teh dropdown
   String value = request.getParameter("value");//get the value that the user entered

   PreparedStatement searchQuery = null;
   String searchString = String.format("Select * from yourtable where %s = ?", colname);

   //create a connection , say con
    searchQuery = con.prepareStatement(searchString);
    searchQuery.setString(1, value);

    ReultSet rs = searchQuery.executeQuery();
```

This solution is only basic a idea so you have to modify to suit. If the columns that you are searching are of different types then you have to cater for that.

Comment: +1 but I'd like to note that this exposes the application to a SQL injection vulnerability. Care should be taken to validate request parameters as well.

Comment: Agreed on the SQL Injection vulnerability. It would be better if you had validation against the value in `colname` to confirm that it is actually a column. A check agains the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` view would be a good idea, or an enumerated list of acceptable column names might be even better.